# MvcContrib Grid not listing data, despite it's existence

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

The following code, located in my view, outputs the following:

```
ViewBag.Count = 4
39d3fe7f-fb1c-4c0f-948e-43093f1d7f85    265ca3c1-9890-4680-b10c-8c7c5e22b26f
f07f0aee-3948-473a-873f-74d446030d36    229db054-e62c-4981-878e-cd0bd5c9a1ac
a92440cd-9393-4d1b-abfb-e705ea739c59    4cd997cf-1715-43b0-9354-0ddf90f33fe6
7c265ae0-7c8e-4dd3-ae76-f52e95138b6e    45254c9a-f078-4d50-bdc8-3e823bdcce41
```

View:

```
ViewBag.Count = @ViewBag.Count
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.ID</td>
        <td>@item.USER_ID</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
@Html.Grid(Model)
```

If there are four records in the ViewBag, then why is MvcContrib Grid not listing them?

Here is my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        ViewBag.Count = db.Directories.Count();

        return View(db.Directories.ToList());
    }
```

Thank you.

**Edit:**

A look at the source code shows just an empty table:

```
<table class="grid"><thead><tr></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="gridrow"></tr><tr class="gridrow_alternate"></tr><tr class="gridrow"></tr><tr class="gridrow_alternate"></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: I notice I am using MVC 4 and MvcContrib says it only supports up to version 3...  might that have something to do with it, or has someone else been able to use it successfully with 4?

Comment: I created a new project in MVC 3 but still the grid appears blank but the ViewBag says there are four records...  I'm still not sure why the grid isn't displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used this, instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/hh288075.aspx

```
@{

  var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort:"Name");

}

@grid.GetHtml()
```